# mixin #5 is not a callable constructor

Tags: dojo

I am creating a  new dijit and in the same html file I am declaring it with markups but I am getting `mixin #5 is not a callable constructor`  from `dojo.js` file, please see the below code snippet and  help me figure out what  I am missing in code, Thanks a lot in advance:

Note: When I am using define() instead of require() then it is not rendering template.

**Code for dijit creation:**

```
require([
    "dojo/_base/declare",
    "dojo/parser",
    "dijit/_WidgetBase",
    "dijit/_TemplatedMixin",
    "dijit/_WidgetsInTemplateMixin",
    "ecm/widget/viewer/FilenetViewer",
    "ecm/widget/dialog/ErrorDialog",
    "ecm/model/Desktop",
    "ecm/model/Repository",
    "ecm/model/Request",
    "dojo/ready",
    "dojo/text!./templates/DocumentViewerWidgetv0.003.html"
], function(declare, parser, _WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin, _WidgetsInTemplateMixin, FilenetViewer, ErrorDialog, Desktop, Repository, Request, ready, template) {
    declare("STViewer", [_WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin, _WidgetsInTemplateMixin, FilenetViewer, ErrorDialog, Desktop, Repository, Request, template], {
        documentID: '',
        templateString: template,
        _setdocumentIDAttr: function(documentID) {
            this.documentID = documentID;
        },
        constructor: function()
        {
            console.log(">> constructor Called <<");
        },
        postCreate: function() {

            console.log("Trace 1 >>" + JSON.stringify(ecm.model.desktop) + "<<");
            this.inherited(arguments);

            var errorDialog = new ErrorDialog();
            dojo.connect(ecm.model.desktop, onMessageAdded",errorDialog,"messageAddedHandler");
                    console.log("Trace 3 >>" + JSON.stringify(ecm.model.desktop) + "<<");

            //Credentials  needs to map with logged in user
            var userId = 'username';
            var password = 'password';

            var desktopName = 'General';


            ecm.model.desktop.servicesUrl = "http://8181testapp001/navigator";
            ecm.model.desktop.loadDesktop(desktopName, function() {
                console.log("Trace 3.2 >> ");

                ecm.model.desktop.userId = userId;

                console.log("Trace 3.3 >>" + userId + "<<,>>" + password + "<<");

                ecm.model.desktop.logon(password, function() {

                    console.log("Trace 3.4 >> successfully logged on to desktop <<");
                    // alert("successfully logged on to desktop");
                    console.log("Trace 4");
                    var dtop = ecm.model.desktop;
                    var repository = dtop.getDefaultRepository();
                    //alert("sucessfully logged on to desktop");
                    console.log("Trace 4.1 >> " + JSON.stringify(repository) + "<<");
                    repository.userId = userId;
                    //repository.setUserId(userId);

                    repository.logon(password, function() {
                        console.log("Trace 4.2 >> successfully logged on to repository <<");
                        var itemId = 'FCEA28D1-6D78-4756-8171-8C33F47316CA';
                        repository.retrieveItem(itemId, function(item) {
                            console.log("Trace 5 >> Document retrieved Successfully <<");

                            this.filenetViewer.setitem(item);
                            console.log("Trace 5.2 >> Document set successfully" + JSON.stringify(this.filenetViewer) + " <<");

                            this.filenetViewer.showItem();

                            console.log("Trace 5.3 >> Document opened Successfully" + JSON.stringify(this.filenetViewer) + " <<");

                        });
                    });//repository.logon end

                });// desktop.logon end
            });//desktop.loadDesktop end

        }, // postCreate

        startup: function() {
            this.inherited(arguments);
        }

    });// declare

    ready(function() {
        parser.parse();
    });
});// require
```

**Template html:**

```
<div>
    <div  data-dojo-attach-point="filenetViewer" data-dojo-type="ecm.widget.viewer.FilenetViewer"  style="width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute; margin: 0; overflow:hidden" isChildWindow="true" showNextPrev="false"sideChrome="0">
</div>
```

**Dijit Markup in body element**

```
<body class="ecm oneui">
   <div >
      <div data-dojo-type="STViewer"  data-dojo-props="documentID:'FCEA28D1-6D78-4756-8171-8C33F47316CA'" > </div>
   </div>
</body>
```